# PHP payment gateway integration using CCAvenue

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I want to pass the value for select payment mode and card type.

My code is :

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.ccavenue.com/shopzone/cc_details.jsp" name="frmTransaction">
     <input type="hidden" name="Merchant_Id" value="<?php echo $Merchant_Id;?>"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value="<?php echo $Amount;?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="Order_Id" value="<?php echo  $Order_Id;?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="Redirect_Url" value="<?php echo $Redirect_Url;?>">
       <input type="hidden" name="Checksum" value="<?php echo $Checksum; ?>"> 


<input type="hidden" name="Merchant_Param" value="<?php echo $Order_Id; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="pay_type" value="Debit Card" /> //credit card, netbanking
        <input type="hidden" name="nb_bid" value="<?php echo $bank_name;?>" /> //VISA, mastercard
```

Here, How to pass pay_type and bank type and preselect the value in CCAvenue gateway. I cannot get any resource for this. Thanks in advace.

Comment: do you have a link tot he Manual for this gateway?

Comment: I think that only works on Custom Checkout Form are you using that method or non seemless

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [cURL](https://php.net/curl). Also, it seems that CC Avenue provides its members with sample PHP code to interact with their web services. I found a manual [here](https://world.ccavenue.com/downloads/CCAVenueWorldIntegrationManual.pdf) that shows where to get sample code from their website on page 12. Using cURL you'll be able to handle the payment before sending it out (adding database records, etc.) and you can obfuscate sensitive data such as your merchant ID.

You'll also probably need to write a second script to handle the response if you're redirecting the user outside of your own site to make the payment (which you might be since you're passing `Redirect_Url`). All this second script will do is check incoming GET/POST fields that they send you (such as an error code or a confirmation number for the user) and use that to add more info to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps to integrate ccavenue in PHP

1. Login to ccavenue dashboard.
2. On the top menu bar navigate to ***Settings > Api keys***. There you can find
    **merchant_id ,access_code,Working key**
3. Navigate to ***Resources > Web Integration Kit***
4. Under this screen there is an option to select ***Testing and Production Environment*** where you can find the testing and production URL.

   > > - Testing URL is not enabled by default you need to ask the support to enable it.
5. On the same screen there is ***Download Integration Kits*** . Click on this and find the Download PHP kit and download the code.
6. Use the downloaded kit according to your requirments.Also you can find the required parameters on ***Integration Methods menu*** as i used the iframe method.
   Hope this will help in integrating the payment gateway